# inserting specific elements into vector using R

Tags: r, indexing, na

Let's say I have two vectors, one that includes NA values, and another that is the length of the first vector after dropping the NA values. I am looking to insert the NA values from the first vector into the second vector, while keeping the position of the NA values the same.

```
a<-c(1,2,3,6,5,NA,4,5,NA,45,6,NA)
b<-c(1,2,4,3,6,5,7,8,40)
```

This can be done by concatenating each component, but this seems extremely tedious, especially since my data are much more complicated than the above example. Something like

```
b[which(is.na(a))]<-NA
```

is what I am looking for, but this of course replaces elements instead of inserting elements like I want. I am at a loss for this even though it seems relatively simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `NA` vector of the same `length` as 'a' and then `replace` based on the non NA elements in 'a'

```
b <- replace(rep(NA, length(a)), !is.na(a), b)
```

-output

```
b
#[1]  1  2  4  3  6 NA  5  7 NA  8 40 NA
```

---

Or more compactly, do the `replace` on 'a'

```
replace(a, !is.na(a), b)
[1]  1  2  4  3  6 NA  5  7 NA  8 40 NA
```